# How can I implement a MUI auto complete like UI element for a vscode web view?

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-code, drop-down-menu, material-ui, dropdown

In the VSCode toolkit [vscode toolkit](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-webview-ui-toolkit) I could not find a searchable dropdown like MUI autocomplete. Is there a way or another place where a searchable dropdown could be found to match the vscode styles?